# How do I reformat the output of re.findall?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Here is my code:

```
def cost_channelID(received_frame):
    received_frame.columns = ['Ad', 'Impressions', 'eCPM', 'Ad Spend']
    Ads = received_frame['Ad']
    ID = []
    for ad in Ads:
        num = re.findall(r'\d{6}',ad)
        ID.append(num)
    ID = pd.Series(ID)
    return(ID)
```

The output is like this:

```
[111234]
[111235]
 ......
[111444]
```

I would like the output to be without the brackets:

```
 111234
 111235
 ......
 144444
```

Comment: They are single-element lists. Why are you using `findall` at all?

Comment: I want to extricate that 6 digit ID number from the Ad column of 'received_frame', an example is 'amob_bun_sp3_111234_3'

Comment: But that only has **one** six-digit number, as apparently do all of the other examples, so *why `findall`?!*

Comment: that's what someone told me would work... looking it up would re.finditer() be better?

Comment: ...why not `search`? You **only want one thing**.

Comment: @bpr [search](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) for first instance would do fine.

Comment: got it, but when I use search I get an output of '<sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000009CA3780>'

Comment: Read the documentation, it explains how to get the value you need from the match.

Answer (score 0):

Getting single element from sequence in Python is fairly simple

```
num = re.findall(r'\d{6}',ad)[0]
```

Although I'd think about why `re.findall` (method that returns sequence) was used in first place.